# Node.js Puppeteer UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning trying to navigate Google Maps

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

(node:15348) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();

page.goto("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Faruk+G%C3%BCll%C3%BCo%C4%9Flu+-+Sunny/@41.0298046,28.7909262,13z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sfaruk+gulluoglu!3m4!1s0x14caa4f77579848b:0x37c42d8b0cecc146!8m2!3d41.0298046!4d28.8151116");
page.waitFor

const seeAllReviewsButton = "#pane > div > div.widget-pane-content.scrollable-y > div > div > div:nth-child(45) > div > div > button > span";
page.click(seeAllReviewsButton);
```

I can't navigate to Google Maps Link Of A Business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `await` before `page.goto`, `page.waitFor` and `page.click` because it return `Promise`. and use `{ waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" }` with `page.goto` to wait for `DOM`. then I fix `seeAllReviewsButton` selector.

The code below works fine with me.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(
    "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Faruk+G%C3%BCll%C3%BCo%C4%9Flu+-+Sunny/@41.0298046,28.7909262,13z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sfaruk+gulluoglu!3m4!1s0x14caa4f77579848b:0x37c42d8b0cecc146!8m2!3d41.0298046!4d28.8151116",
    { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" }
  );

  const seeAllReviewsButton =
    "#pane > div > div.widget-pane-content.scrollable-y > div > div > div.section-hero-header-title > div.section-hero-header-title-top-container > div.section-hero-header-title-description > div.section-hero-header-title-description-container > div > div.gm2-body-2.section-rating-line > span:nth-child(3) > span > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1) > button";

  await page.waitForSelector(seeAllReviewsButton);
  await page.click(seeAllReviewsButton);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

**There are few corrections needed:** You need to await `page.goto`, `page.waitFor`, and `page.click` methods. And most importantly `page.waitFor()` is a method and it takes *string or number or function* as arguments and all of these methods return a promise. So they need to be awaited or do then on it.